# How fix the loop that repeat the satellite information in the list?

Tags: android, gps, satellite

i create an application that show gps sensor satellite informations. But the iterator loop isn't right, information shows as text never stop to update. I would like a unique information for each satellite and not the same information. how fix it?

```
  if (statoGps != null) {
                Iterable<GpsSatellite> listSat = statoGps.getSatellites();
                Iterator<GpsSatellite> sat = listSat.iterator();
                int visibleSats = 0;
                while (sat.hasNext()) {
                   GpsSatellite satellite = sat.next();
                   gpsStats += "SATELLITE " + (visibleSats++) + 
                                  "PRN: " + satellite.getPrn() +                     
                                  "SNR: " + satellite.getSnr() + 
                                  "azimuth: " + satellite.getAzimuth() + 
                                  "el: " + satellite.getElevation() + 
                                  "fix: " + satellite.usedInFix() + "\n"; 


                }
                elencoSat.setText(gpsStats);  
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove while loop, keep only the inside code. This will print the info once only.

Comment: thanks but does not work...i resolved whit clear gpsStats before the while loop...